# CPT requires manage_options and edit_posts for some reason

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

I made a CPT called `sponsor`. I set `map_meta_cap` to `true` and `capability_type` to `sponsor`.

I created a custom role that has `edit_sponsors`, as well as all the other stems (`delete`, `publish`, etc., each with `_sponsor` appended — and another with `sponsors` for good measure). I confirmed all this in the database: the capabilities are being added correctly.

Nevertheless, my custom role is getting access errors. In the admin menu there is indeed an item 'Sponsors' to bring up all posts of that CPT. But when I click it, I get an access error.

So I tried using my admin user to get direct links to various functions (e.g. `example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=sponsor`), and it turns out that the custom role can't create new sponsors either, but it can for some reason edit an existing sponsor created by the admin user.

I narrowed down the capabilities till I found the ones responsible. It turns out that by adding `manage_options` to the custom role, it can access the list of posts of that CPT. And by adding `edit_posts` to the custom role, it can add a new post of that CPT.

But I'd rather not have to give the role those capabilities. Is it really the case that they need those capabilities for two functions? What could I be doing wrong?

---

Some snippets...

CPT registration (some relevant args)

```
// in function hooked to 'init'

$args = [
    'labels' => $labels,
    'description' => 'Individual sponsor for the auction',
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => $menu_slug,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => false,
    'supports' => false,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'sponsor'
];

register_post_type('ausp', $args);
```

Adding capabilities to the role. The stems are from [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#capabilities). (Some of the plural/singular ones are redundant; out of laziness I just added both to all to make sure I got them all and can't see how that could harm it.)

```php
// in function hooked to 'admin-init'

$caps = ['upload_files', 'view_admin_dashboard', 'manage_options', 'edit_posts'];

$stems = ['create', 'publish', 'read', 'edit', 'edit_others', 'edit_published',
'edit_private', 'delete', 'delete_others', 'delete_published', 'delete_private'];

foreach($stems as $stem) {
    foreach(['s', ''] as $plural) {
        $cap = sprintf('%s_sponsor%s', $stem, $plural);
        $caps[] = $cap;
    }
}

foreach($caps as $cap) {
    $role->add_cap($cap);
}
```

When I look at `wp_user_roles` in the `wp_options` table of the database, I can see that these capabilities are all being added.

Comment: It's impossible to say what you might be doing wring without seeing any code. You should share the code you used to register the post type, as well as the full list of capabilities you granted.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks, have added. Let me know if you think more needs to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

After running into a very similar problem as OP, I determined that my issue was caused by another function I had added to `functions.php` to group custom post types under one dashboard menu.

To fix, I changed `manage_options` to `edit_posts` in the custom menu function `add_menu_page()`:

```
/**
 * Register a custom menu page.
 */
function wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        __( 'Child Pages', 'textdomain' ),
        'Child Pages',
        'edit_posts', /* was 'manage_options' */
        'child-pages.php',
        '',
        'dashicons-index-card',
        22
    );
}
```